Naming of transactions in postgresql
According to different websites, a transaction begins with
BEGIN TRANSACTION [optional name];

And then something like this follows:
DROP TABLE a_fancy_table;
COMMIT [optional name];

But if I try this with a name in postgres, it doesn't work. Is it simply not possible? Will it be possible in a future version? I haven't found any definite statement on the internet about this.

This is the primary source of truth: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/17/sql-begin.html, there is no name there.

It doesn't really matter what some undisclosed random website says if the syntax doesn't work and it is not even mentioned in the official documentation. Regarding the question, savepoints get a name so they can be manipulated afterwards, not sure if that suits your needs.

Out of curiosity, are those different websites maybe discussing the features of a different product, such as Microsoft SQL Server?

@ÁlvaroGonzález Yes and no. Mixed.

@bereal I read it. But from experience I always consider the possibility of incompleteness.

From the comments I conclude, that there is no way. And there is no clandestine knowledge, which I'm not aware of.

If you aren't going to trust the official documentation from the people who build the database, I don't know why you'd expect random-internet-person to know any better.

if you need to name a transaction, you might be doing something wrong!

Or did you mean a prepared transaction or savepoint? Both can have a "name", but are different from a transaction.

@FrankHeikens Neither. Transactions. Doesn't work, my question is answered. I just haven't found anyone saying it like this. Now I have it.

You can't name a transaction in PostgreSQL - they do have names/identifiers, but those are entirely handled by the database. You can look it up with Transaction ID and Snapshot Information Functions but you can't set it yourself:

pg_current_xact_id () → xid8
Returns the current transaction's ID. It will assign a new one if the current transaction does not have one already (because it has not performed any database updates); see Section 74.1 for details. If executed in a subtransaction, this will return the top-level transaction ID; see Section 74.3 for details.

As already hinted by @Frank Heikens in the comments, you can give a transaction an identifier if you wish to save it and apply it later (PREPARE TRANSACTION for a two-phase commit) or you can name a sub-transaction, a SAVEPOINT.
It's a guess, but if you're looking to have some kind of transaction name internally, you can use set_config('my.transaction_name','the_name',true) with is_local set to true, or just query the pg_current_xact_id(). If that's for some kind of synchronisation purposes, advisory locks might also help.
As to verifying things that are missing or unclear in the documentation, you can always refer to the source. The grammar rules are defined in in src/backend/parser/gram.y and around 11k lines in, it says that the transaction opening statement can be followed by transaction_mode_list_or_empty which is a list of these:
transaction_mode_item:
            ISOLATION LEVEL iso_level
                    { $$ = makeDefElem("transaction_isolation",
                                       makeStringConst($3, @3), @1); }
            | READ ONLY
                    { $$ = makeDefElem("transaction_read_only",
                                       makeIntConst(true, @1), @1); }
            | READ WRITE
                    { $$ = makeDefElem("transaction_read_only",
                                       makeIntConst(false, @1), @1); }
            | DEFERRABLE
                    { $$ = makeDefElem("transaction_deferrable",
                                       makeIntConst(true, @1), @1); }
            | NOT DEFERRABLE
                    { $$ = makeDefElem("transaction_deferrable",
                                       makeIntConst(false, @1), @1); }
        ;

which combined with these:
iso_level:  READ UNCOMMITTED                        { $$ = "read uncommitted"; }
            | READ COMMITTED                        { $$ = "read committed"; }
            | REPEATABLE READ                       { $$ = "repeatable read"; }
            | SERIALIZABLE                          { $$ = "serializable"; }
        ;

matches exactly what's in the doc for BEGIN:
BEGIN [ WORK | TRANSACTION ] [ transaction_mode [, ...] ]

where transaction_mode is one of:

    ISOLATION LEVEL { SERIALIZABLE | REPEATABLE READ | READ COMMITTED | READ UNCOMMITTED }
    READ WRITE | READ ONLY
    [ NOT ] DEFERRABLE

